# How to debug sharepoint webservice?

Tags: visual-studio, web-services, debugging

I've followed [Walkthrough: Creating a Custom ASP.NET Web Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms464040%28v=office.14%29.aspx) and everything works fine. 
I just want to know how to enable debugging for this web service over network. Could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i know it has been long time ago, but i hope it helps some one
kindly check the following link:
[Debug Sharepoint Web Service](http://hager.softmarvels.com/index.php/blog/show/debug-web-service)

Comment: Hager, please add at least some high-level information regarding the answer. Blogs posts and sometimes entire blogs get deleted. Having at least some information will ensure that others can gain some value from your question/answer in the future.

Comment: Hager, the link is dead. Can you add details about it here?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a client console application for debugging purposes.

**Follow the next Steps:**

A) Create a Console Application

[image]

B) In the Solution Explorer, right-click on your project and select Add Service Reference.
and the Add Service Reference dialog, click the Advanced button.

[image]

C) In the Service Reference settings dialog, click on the Add Web Reference button.

[image]

D) In the "Add Web Reference" dialog, enter your web service URL.
for example :  `http://myserver/_layouts/mywebservice/mywebservice.asmx`
press enter, and you'll see your methods.
Finally press on the "Add Reference" button.

[image]

This way you can debug your web service using a console application.

Comment: thank you for your reply,
     i need to trace into the web service, i've a piece of code which throws an exception and i need to trace it